# Is there a way to modify multiple curve slopes in Graph Editor at the same time?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

[image]

How can I adjust several handles on one side at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Select the keyframe (which selects both side handles) press <kbd>C</kbd> for [Circular Selection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html#circle-select) tool and de-select the side you don't want.